# Origen de la expresión "cinco estrellas"

Tags: modismos

> A: ¡Hola! ¿Cómo estás, compa?
>
> B: Todo de perlas y tú?
>
> A: ¡5 estrellas, gracias!

Me gustaría saber de dónde viene la expresión "cinco estrellas ". ¿Se usa mucho en el norte o el sur del país?

Comment: Cuando te refieres a "en el norte o el sur del país", ¿a qué país te refieres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En España la categoría de los hoteles se mide por el número de "estrellas". Una o dos estrellas es un hostal. Un hotel de cinco estrellas es de mucho lujo. Este sistema de calificación se usa en muchas otras cosas (los restaurantes suelen usar en cambio "cinco tenedores", pero la guía Michelín, una de las más prestigiosas en gastronomía, usa [las estrellas](http://elgranchef.imujer.com/6791/que-son-las-estrellas-michelin)).

Aparte, hay una conocida marca de cerveza, Mahou, que tiene una gama de cervezas denominada [*Cinco estrellas*](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahou#Producci.C3.B3n_cervecera). Los anuncios de televisión hacían mucho énfasis en realzar el aspecto de "cinco estrellas = máxima calidad". En dichos anuncios se producían conversaciones como las que describes en la pregunta, y con el tiempo esas conversaciones fueron copiadas por el ciudadano de a pie.

Por eso "cinco estrellas" es sinónimo de "sobresaliente", "perfecto" etc.

Comment: La expresión se usa también en España entonces? No sabía :)

Comment: Yo creo que no es una expresión propia del Español, sino una metáfora universal.

Comment: No todos los hispanohablantes saben esta expresión.

Comment: 5 estrellas es la medida universal de valoración de hoteles, luego se puede intuir que el significado es "de lujo". Tampoco es muy común decir que estás 5 estrellas. En España quizá es mas famoso por lo que comenta Diego de la cerveza Mahou.