# Comparación de "flor y nata" y "mamey"

Tags: vocabulario, comida

En una [pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18859/9385) apareció la frase *flor y nata* que significa *lo mejor*:

> En esa reunión estaba la *flor y nata* de la sociedad: reyes, ministros, jueces...

Quisiera comparar esta frase con *mamey*, que aprendí en México para describir la variedad más exótica y rica de una fruta, por ejemplo, en un restaurante el mesero se jacta del plato de fruta:

> Tenemos papaya mamey.

La papaya mamey es por dentro un color casi rosado, no amarillo como la papaya común y corriente.  También hay un mango mamey.

Imágenes: primero la papaya mamey y luego la papaya normal.

[image: papaya mamey]

[image: papay normal (común y corriente)]

Creo que he oído *mamey* extendido a otras cosas, por ejemplo

> Pero mira, mi amor, te lo hice especial, esto no es una sopa de pollo cualquiera, es caldo mamey.

Bueno, estoy dudando de mi memoria en eso, y también quiero preguntar

#### - ¿Se entiende *mamey* en otros países si se usa para ciertas frutas, o en un contexto más general?

#### - Comparemos el uso de *flor y nata* y *mamey* -- ¿en cuáles contextos se puede usar cada una de estas expresiones, y en cuáles no se puede usar?

(Hay una fruta *mamey* pero creo que no tiene nada que ver.)

Véase esta definición del DRAE:

> X 1.  adj. Cu. Referido a cosa, de excelente calidad.

Supongo que "Cu" se refiere a Cuba.

Comment: En España no se utiliza la palabra *mamey* en ningún sentido, para ver sus usos en otros paises mírate esto: http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=mamey

Comment: Mejor si contesta alguien de un país donde se use esa expresión, que pueda explicarlo mejor

Comment: Esta pregunta podría tener una respuesta _community wiki_ en la que usuarios cuyo español es de una región distinta contestasen diciendo si se entiende "mamey" con ese significado en su país y si no con qué otros significados se le entiende.

Answer (score 4):

Según la entrada del DRAE para [mamey](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O6DAO0a)

> 5. m. coloq. **Cuba**. Cosa de excelente calidad. U. t. c. adj.

Yo, con mi español de España, no habría entendido "mamey". LA entrada del diccionario panhispánico no aporta demasiado nuevo. La del diccionario de americanismos es igual a la del DRAE (que es la que aportas en la pregunta y, sí, como hemos visto en la del DRAE ese "Cu" es Cuba).

> X.    1.  adj. Cu. Referido a cosa, de excelente calidad.

Curiosamente, según el diccionario de americanismos en México [mamey](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=mamey) puede ser usado como un vulgarismo que tiene ciertas connotaciones sexuales

> II. 1.  m. Mx, Gu, Ho, Pe. Felación. vulg; pop.
>
> IV.   1.  m. Mx. Vulva. vulg.

Creo que esa entrada del diccionario de americanismos es la que más información te va a dar sobre los significados "regionales" de "mamey".

Entiendo que "[flor y nata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I6Rb5ZS)" es

> 1. f. flor (‖ parte más **escogida**). La flor y nata de la sociedad.

Mientras que "mamey" más que "selecto, algo escogido porque destaca entre muchos otros, lo mejor de lo mejor" (que es el significado de "flor y nata") significa "muy bueno, extraordinario, excepcional". Desde luego en ciertos contextos uno puede implicar lo otro.

Yo creo que en España usaríamos las expresiones "pata negra"<sup>1</sup> (por el [jamón de pata negra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MKcPlIi)) o "[cinco estrellas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12607/5481)" antes que "mamey".

---

1. Pata Negra es un término comúnmente utilizado para referirse a los productos de **alta calidad** derivados del cerdo ibérico. Literalmente hace referencia al color de la piel de la mayoría de estos cerdos y al de sus pezuñas; sin embargo no siempre su color es negro.

La expresión "[pata negra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S71hGRM%7CS72dH32#DE7aXEP)" no se limita únicamente a los alimentos, se usa para decir que algo es de excelente calidad o auténtico y vale para cualquier cosa.

Comment: ...¿Pata negra?

Comment: Mmm, yum yum.  ¿Agregas la explicación a la respuesta?  // Quisiera ver el rango de usos de "flor y nata" y "pata negra" si es que su uso no es universal, y también ver si hay casos donde se pueda usar los dos.  Sospecho que "pata negra" y "mamey" van a coincidir en limitarse a los alimentos.

Comment: @aparente001 *pata negra* no se limita únicamente a los alimentos, se usa para decir que algo es de excelente calidad o auténtico y vale para cualquier cosa.

Comment: @blonfu - Que alguien agregue esto a la respuesta, por favor.